# How to force select_related() to select ForeignKeys that have null=True attribute?

Tags: django

Model1 has a ForeignKey to Model2. And Model2 has a ForeignKey(Model3, null=True, blank=True) to Model3. By default, when I use select_related() on Model1, Model3 is not selected because of null=True. How can I force select_related() to follow a foreign_key that has has null=True?

The only way I can think of is to explicitly select these foreign keys:

```
model1s = Model1.objects.all().select_related('model2', 'model2__model3')
```

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 18):

Yes, that is the way you would go about selecting related items with null=True.

Straight from the [docs for select_related](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4):

> You can refer to any ForeignKey or OneToOneField relation in the list of fields passed to select_related. Ths includes foreign keys that have null=True (unlike the default select_related() call).

Is there a reason you need a different way to perform this action?  If not, you have it right already.

Comment: I have many ForeignKey fields that are set to null=True. I'd rather not list them all. But I guess I'll have to.

Comment: You are right again.  It does seem like a lot of typing but this is technically a bit of a corner use case.  Better than not being able to  select_related at all though.  Please add your own answer if you come up with something different.

Comment: Spent ages searching for this.. thanks for the question and the answer!

Comment: When wrapping legacy, read-only tables in Django models, I do not always take the time to figure out which need blank=True and null=True because it often does not matter. Matters greatly for foreign keys and `select_related`.